# Avoid form submitting twice if user quickly clicks submit buttons two times

Tags: python, html, flask, wtforms

I've been struggling with this one and I can't get a proper answer.

Disabling the button after click doesn't help because it needs to be working in case of not valid request.

Shouldn't the form already being handling this sort of situations since in app.py I redirect after *form.validate_on_submit()*

Any idea on how to stop form from being submitted twice on quick submit button presses?

**register.html:**

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="mb-5">
    <h2 class="text-center mt-3">Register</h2>

    <form action="/register" method="post" class="mt-3 mb-3" novalidate autocomplete="off">

        {{ form.csrf_token }}

    {# Username #}
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ form.username.label(class="form-label") }}
      {{ form.username(class="form-control") }}
      {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <span style="color: red">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    {# Email #}
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ form.email.label(class="form-label") }}
      {{ form.email(class="form-control", autocomplete="username", autocapitalize="off") }}
      {% for error in form.email.errors %}
            <span style="color: red">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
            <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>

    {# Password #}
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ form.password.label(class="form-label") }}
      {{ form.password(class="form-control", autocomplete="new-password") }}
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
            <span style="color: red">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    {# Passowrd confirm #}
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ form.confirm.label(class="form-label") }}
      {{ form.confirm(class="form-control", autocomplete="new-password") }}
      {% for error in form.confirm.errors %}
            <span style="color: red">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    {# Submit button #}
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-secondary mt-2", id="submit-button")}}
    </div>
    </form>

    <div class="text-center">
        <p class="d-inline me-3">You have an account?</p>
        <a href="{{url_for('login')}}">Login</a>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
  form = RegisterForm()

  if form.validate_on_submit():
    
    hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data)
    new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data.lower(), password=hashed_password)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
  else:
    print(form.errors.items())
  
  return render_template("register.html", form=form)
```

[image: Below you can see the terminal]

You can see in the terminal the same datas being submitted 3 times, the first time the go to database and the other two times they get rejected by server side validation.

Comment: _"Shouldn't the form already being handling this sort of situations since in app.py I redirect after form.validate_on_submit()"_ - if the redirect had already happened - then the form and the button would already be gone, so the user _could_ not even submit a second time.

Comment: _"Disabling the button after click doesn't help because it needs to be working in case of not valid request."_ - but aren't you rendering the form anew anyway, in case the validation fails - `return render_template("register.html", form=form)`? Then the button should not be disabled any more, because it is not even the _same_ button element any more, but a new one.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the form from being submitted twice if the user quickly clicks the submit button, you can use a technique known as "form disabling" using JavaScript. Here's how you can modify your HTML template and JavaScript to achieve this:

make the register.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="mb-5">
    <h2 class="text-center mt-3">Register</h2>

    <form action="/register" method="post" class="mt-3 mb-3" novalidate autocomplete="off" id="register-form">

        {{ form.csrf_token }}

    {# Username #}
        <!-- ... (your existing code) ... -->

    {# Submit button #}
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-secondary mt-2", id="submit-button")}}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("register-form").addEventListener("submit", function () {
        document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have tried it and It doesn't work, It still gets submitted multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what the problem was. Simply I was putting the javascript outside of the jinja endblock block, on the bottom of the page. Now the javascript works.